# How to validate a url field whether the website url is valid format or not in forms.py and shows the error in template

Tags: django, django-class-based-views

I am using django class based views. I am trying to validate the url field in forms.py file. To check whether the given url is valid format or not and return the errors in template page. Can anyone help me to do this.

```
def clean_website(self):
   website = self.cleaned_data.get("website")
   val = URLValidators(verify_exists=False)
   val(website)
```

It's not working for me.Please any one help me to validate the field and return the error.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does the rest of your form logic look like?

Comment: what do you want rest of it??

Comment: "It's not working" is a terribly useless statement. What do you expect and what does it actually do? The complete view and form would also help us help you.

Answer (score 0):

try returning the data at the end of the method:

```
return val(website)
```